# Mercurial + TeamCity - Recommended setup

Tags: mercurial, teamcity

Does anyone have any recommended best practice for setting up TeamCity with Mercurial? We'd previously been using SVN as our source control provider which worked beautifully, but I'm struggling to get this working as smoothly with Mercurial. I'm sure part of it is some time to adjust to the new model, but even so...

The main issue seems to be that TeamCity keeps insisting on doing complete clean checkouts on almost every build. It seems to be randomly changing the hash it uses to determine where it stores the source code (despite the configuration not changing).

As we're using bitbucket to host our Mercurial repositories, the server pulling down 150MB+ of source code and dependencies each time is grinding our deployment and continuous build processes to a halt.

Would appreciate any input on what we might be doing wrong here. Thank you.

Comment: Have you specified which branch it should pull from? Also, are you using agent-side or server-side checkout?

Comment: @Lasse sorry, only just seen your comment. It's just coming from the default branch - (should I specify explicitly?), and using server-side check out

Answer (score 3):

Have you made sure that Clean all files before build setting is not checked?

Also what helped my setup was to define a checkout directory in each build configuration => Version Control Settings (eg. C:\TCProjects) thus all repos are checked out in the same directory and it is also easier to check what is happening in contrast with the auto-generated hash directories.

[image]